# Can I perform a find/replace driven by a CSV/Excel file?

Tags: visual-studio-code, replace

I have to perform a find/replace across my project's files using a rename rule-set which I have in CSV format.

My rename CSV is simple and in the format `from value,to value`:

```
foo,bar
car,dog
...
zip,zip
```

All from and to values are exact (so no need to do weird regex).

Is there any way (even w/ an extension) to feed this CSV into VS Code and have it perform the find and replace against all files in my project?

I can of course reformat this CSV to other formats (JSON, excel, etc.) fairly easily if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using Batch Replace extension for VS Code.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=angelomollame.batch-replacer

Originally I had tried this extension but it wasnt working. I had an ah-ha momement as to why (i have about 500 replace rules). I also use a local history VS Code extension which creates a (massive) local history in a .history folder in the workspace. This extension was choking on processing the 10,000's of files in that (since technically its in my workspace).

Once i excluded that, it worked - though it did take ~1 min to process all my files, and during that time there is no indication that its running.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a simple python script to do the replacing for you.